# Zero and inverse element in abelian group of extensions of modules

Tags: category-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

Let $A,B$ be modules. An extension of $A$ by $B$ is a short exact sequence $$B\to E\to A$$. Let $Ext(A,B)$ be a set of equivalence classes of such modules $E$. The book said that this admit an abelian group structure. I would like to confirm is it true that the zero object is the split short exact sequence
$B\to A\oplus B\to A$? I wanna prove this, but I am stuck at making an isomorphism between $E$ and $E\oplus A\oplus B$. And I have no clue about the inverse element of $B\to E\to A$: that is $B\to X\to A$ such that $E\oplus X$ is isomorphic to $A\oplus B$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't get an isomorphism between $E$ and $E\oplus A\oplus B$ since these will rarely be isomorphic. You need to look at what the actual sum is on the extensions (it is not just direct sum).

Comment: My thesis contains just this and all the proofs :-)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, yes. I think that does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two extensions 
$$A\to E \to B$$
and
$$A\to F \to B$$
we define the sum of them to be be the quotient of the pullback $X$ on the morphisms 
$$\pi_e: E\to B$$
$$\pi_f: F\to B$$
with the module
$$N=\{\imath_e(a)\oplus-\imath_f(a):a\in A\}$$

Then the baer sum is $X/N$. Let $A\oplus B$ be given and $E$ an extension, then we have.
$$X=\{(a\oplus b)\oplus e:\pi(a\oplus b)=\pi_e(e)\}$$
$$=\{a\oplus b\oplus e:b=\pi_e(e)\}$$
$$=\{(a\oplus b)\oplus e:b=\pi_e(e)\}$$
$$\cong\{a \oplus e\}$$
$$=A\oplus E$$
and for the submodule we have through a similar reasoning that $N\cong A\cong A\oplus 0$
and taking their quotient you get the rest. I recommend you look into MacLanes book on it.

Comment: I do not get what is wrong with my definition and why it does not work. I think something should have been missing. But the way you define the zero element works. Thanks.

Comment: The inverse is just the same chain but the negative epimorphism. What is wrong is that you cannot establish them being equivalent through commutative diagrams, like this we can.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your explanation :)

Comment: @ChenMLing welcome, it all really boils down to generalizations and commutative diagrams, as i mentioned i did an entire thesis on this :-)